# Number of ways to write n as a sum of powers of 2

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there any algorithm to find out that how many ways are there for write a number for example n , with sum of power of 2 ?

example : for 4 there are four ways :

```
4 = 4 
4 = 2 + 2 
4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
4 = 2 + 1 + 1
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to differentiate between 4 = 2 + 1 + 1 and 4 = 1 + 1 + 2 or are those viewed as the same?

Comment: Have you solved for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and seen if a trivial pattern emerges?

Comment: Thanks, no i don't want to differentiate between them. and i saw a pattern like fibo algorithm but i am not sure.

Comment: Isn't it just a subset-sum problem ? Or are you interested in a closed-form formula?

Comment: I think about an hour but I'm not sure. this a question that i faced.

Comment: There is lots of information including recurrence relations for this sequence at the [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences - A018819](http://oeis.org/A018819).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose g(m) is the number of ways to write m as a sum of powers of 2. We use  f(m,k) to represent the number of ways to  write m as a sum of powers of 2 with all the numbers' power is less than or equal to k. Then we can reduce to the equation:

```
if m==0 f(m,k)=1;    
if k<0 f(m,k)=0;    
if k==0 f(m,k)=1;    
if m>=power(2,k) f(m,k)=f(m-power(2,k),k)+f(m,k-1);//we can use power(2,k) as one of the numbers or not.    
else f(m,k)=f(m,k-1);
```

Take 6 as an example:

```
g(6)=f(6,2)
=f(2,2)+f(6,1)
=f(2,1)+f(4,1)+f(6,0)
=f(0,1)+f(2,0)+f(2,1)+f(4,0)+1
=1+1+f(0,1)+f(2,0)+1+1
=1+1+1+1+1+1
=6
```

Here is the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int log2(int n)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while (n>>=1) 
    {
        ++ret;      
    }
    return ret;
}

int power(int x,int y)
{
    int ret=1,i=0;
    while(i<y)
    {
        ret*=x;
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}

int getcount(int m,int k)
{
    if(m==0)return 1;
    if(k<0)return 0;
    if(k==0)return 1;
    if(m>=power(2,k))return getcount(m-power(2,k),k)+getcount(m,k-1);
    else return getcount(m,k-1);

}

int main()
{
    int m=0;
    while(cin>>m)
    {
        int k=log2(m);
        cout<<getcount(m,k)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

A recursive definition of the sequence (from Peter's link to A018819):

[f(n) = 1 if n = 0, Sum(j = 0..[n/2], f(j)) if n > 0 http://mathurl.com/nuaarfm.png](http://mathurl.com/nuaarfm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the number of ways in which you can express a number as the sum of the power of 2.
firstly you need to find the number set bits in that particular number because the number of the set bit will give us the minimum numbers required to express it as the sum of the power of 2.
The maximum numbers required to express it as a sum of the power of 2 will the number itself because you can express it as a sum of 1 ( because 2 the power 0 is 1).
example: 5 can be expressed as ( 1+1+1+1+1)

hence the total number of ways to express a number as the  power of 2 is simply given by the formula -->
 let the no be x 
                ( x - no of set bits in x ) + 1 ;
for example, let the number be 17 
then the no of set bits in 17 is 2 
hence the no of ways are ( 17 - 2 ) + 1 = 16 ;